# What does each number in a WordNet sense mean?

Tags: nlp, wordnet

WordNet senses encode some information about the sense in the ID. Based on the `lemma_from_key` method [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html), we can see that the first three numbers are *pos_number*, *lexname_index*, and *lex_id*. What are the other two? Is there documentation on what (more specifically) each of those mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ss_type:lex_filenum:lex_id:head_word:head_id
```

> lemma is the ASCII text of the word or collocation as found in the
>   WordNet database index file corresponding to pos . lemma is in lower
>   case, and collocations are formed by joining individual words with an
>   underscore (_ ) character.
>
> ss_type is a one digit decimal integer representing the synset type
>   for the sense. See Synset Type below for a listing of the numbers
>   corresponding to each synset type.
>
> lex_filenum is a two digit decimal integer representing the name of
>   the lexicographer file containing the synset for the sense. See
>   lexnames(5WN) for the list of lexicographer file names and their
>   corresponding numbers.
>
> lex_id is a two digit decimal integer that, when appended onto lemma ,
>   uniquely identifies a sense within a lexicographer file. lex_id
>   numbers usually start with 00 , and are incremented as additional
>   senses of the word are added to the same file, although there is no
>   requirement that the numbers be consecutive or begin with 00 . Note
>   that a value of 00 is the default, and therefore is not present in
>   lexicographer files. Only non-default lex_id values must be explicitly
>   assigned in lexicographer files. See wninput(5WN) for information on
>   the format of lexicographer files.
>
> head_word is only present if the sense is in an adjective satellite
>   synset. It is the lemma of the first word of the satellite's head
>   synset.
>
> head_id is a two digit decimal integer that, when appended onto
>   head_word , uniquely identifies the sense of head_word within a
>   lexicographer file, as described for lex_id . There is a value in this
>   field only if head_word is present.

From: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/senseidx5wn